WebRTC connection fails between devices on different networks despite successful STUN/TURN configuration
I have a WebRTC video chat application built with Angular that works perfectly when testing locally (same network) but fails when devices are on different networks. Here are the specific details:
Environment

Angular application with Socket.io for signaling
Twilio STUN/TURN servers configured
Devices: Two MacBooks on different mobile hotspots

What Works

Local video stream initialization
Signaling server connection and message exchange
ICE candidate gathering (getting both STUN and TURN candidates)
Connection works perfectly when testing on same network

What Doesn't Work

Connection fails when devices are on different networks
ICE connection state transitions from "checking" to "disconnected"
DTLS state remains "new" and never completes handshake
No packets are being sent/received (all counters at 0)

private setupPeerConnection(targetUserId: string) {
  this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [
      { urls: 'stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478' },
      {
        urls: [
          'turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp',
          'turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=tcp',
          'turn:global.turn.twilio.com:443?transport=tcp'
        ],
        username: '...',
        credential: '...'
      }
    ],
    iceTransportPolicy: 'all',
    bundlePolicy: 'max-bundle',
    rtcpMuxPolicy: 'require'
  });
}

What I've Tried

Forced TURN usage with iceTransportPolicy: 'relay'
Added ICE restart on connection failure
Verified TURN credentials are valid
Implemented reconnection logic
Added proper error handling and state monitoring

The WebRTC stats show ICE candidates are gathered successfully but the connection never establishes. What could be preventing the connection between devices on different networks despite having proper TURN configuration?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
